# How to change DOM using onSubmit in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react for the front end of a search application.

When user submits a query and a list of results pop up, each with a button that says "Learn More". When the "Learn More" button is pressed, the list of results should all disappear and be replaced with the information on that topic that was selected.

The search bar above should stay in place, if a user searches new information, the learn more info should go away and the new list of results should appear.

I am having trouble displaying the learn more information.

The biggest issue I am having is that I have to use the form with the onSubmit function and as soon as the onSubmit function is called my results will stay for a few seconds and then everything will disappear.

The following shows the parts of my file related to the issue

```
class Search extends React.Component {

 learnMore(obj){
   //Here is where i would like to replace the results class with the learn more info. obj.learnMore has the info stored
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="search">
       <div className="search-bar">
       // Here is where my search bar is, results of search get added to results array
       </div>

       <div className= "results">
       {this.state.results.map((obj) =>
         <div key={obj.id}>
            <p> {obj.name} </p>
            <form id= "learn-more-form" onSubmit={() => {this.learnMore(obj); return false;}}>
               <input type="submit" value="Learn More"/>
           </form>
         </div>
       )}
       </div>

     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with some dummy data? I wouldn't use a form here. I think adding a `<button onClick={() => this.learnMore(obj)}>Learn more</button>` is enough here. Inside `this.learnMore` you can update the `state` for your `learnMoreObject` and that will do a re-render of that info.

Comment: It is a requirement that I use a form. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: ```hit.learnMore has the info stored``` can you elaborate a bit about this comment? what is ```hit.learnMore` ? props?

Comment: my bad, that should be obj.learnMore has the string that should be displayed if the Learn More button corresponding to that object is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this scenario. In this case, I recommend separating [containers from components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). The container will handle all things `state` and update its children `components` accordingly.

Please note that this example uses a lot of ES6 syntaxes. Please read the following to understand how some of it works: [fat arrow functions](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26), [ES6 destruction](https://codeburst.io/using-destructing-for-objects-and-arrays-and-its-practical-examples-e3ebb13170e5), [spread operator](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/spread-operator-and-rest-parameter-in-javascript-es6-4416a9f47e5e), [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), [a controlled react form utilizing event handlers and state](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), [array filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [type checking with PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

It's a lot to take in, so if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Search For User]

---

**containers/SeachForm**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import LearnMore from "../../components/LearnMore";
import Results from "../../components/Results";
import SearchBar from "../../components/Searchbar";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Bob",
    age: 32,
    email: "bob@example.com",
    registered: moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(),
    description: "Bob is a stay at home dad."
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Jane",
    age: 43,
    email: "jane@example.com",
    registered: moment("20010810", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(),
    description: "Jane is a CEO at Oracle."
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Yusef",
    age: 21,
    email: "yusef@example.com",
    registered: moment("20180421", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(),
    description: "Yusef is a student at UC Berkeley."
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Dasha",
    age: 29,
    email: "dasha@example.com",
    registered: moment("20050102", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(),
    description: "Dasha is an owner of a local antique shop."
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Polina",
    age: 18,
    email: "dasha@example.com",
    registered: moment("20190102", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(),
    description: "Polina works at a local movie theather."
  }
];

const initialState = {
  searchQuery: "",
  results: data, // <== change this to an empty array if you don't want to show initial user data
  learnMore: false
};

class SearchForm extends Component {
  state = { ...initialState }; // spreading out the initialState object defined above; it'll be the same as: "state = { searchQuery: "",  results: data, learnMore: false }; " 

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents a page refresh

    if (!this.state.searchQuery) return null; // prevents empty search submissions

    this.setState({
      results: data.filter(
        person => person.name.toLowerCase() === this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()
      ) // filters the dataset with the "searchQuery" (lowercased names) and returns the result if it finds a match
    });
  };

  handleSearch = ({ target: { value } }) =>
    this.setState({ searchQuery: value }); // updates searchQuery input with an event.target.value 

  handleReset = () => this.setState({ ...initialState }); // resets to initial state

  handleLearnMore = person => {
    this.setState({ learnMore: true, results: person }); // sets learnMore to true (to show the "LearnMore" component) and sets results to the selected user
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="container">
      <SearchBar
        handleReset={this.handleReset}
        handleSearch={this.handleSearch}
        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        searchQuery={this.state.searchQuery}
      />
      {!this.state.learnMore ? ( // if learnMore is false, then show "Results"
        <Results  
          results={this.state.results}
          handleLearnMore={this.handleLearnMore}
        />
      ) : (
        <LearnMore {...this.state.results} /> // otherwise, show LearnMore
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchForm;
```

**components/SearchBar**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SearchBar = ({
  handleReset,
  handleSearch,
  handleSubmit,
  searchQuery
}) => (
  <div className="search">
    <div className="search-bar">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="uk-input"
          value={searchQuery}
          placeholder="Search for a name"
          onChange={handleSearch}
        />
        <div className="button-container">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger reset"
            onClick={handleReset}
          >
            Reset
          </button>
          <button type="submit" className="uk-button uk-button-primary submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);

SearchBar.propTypes = {
  handleReset: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  searchQuery: PropTypes.string
};

export default SearchBar;
```

**components/Results**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Results = ({ handleLearnMore, results }) => (
  <div className="results">
    {results && results.length > 0 ? (
      results.map(person => (
        <div key={person.id} className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-width-1-2@m">
          <div className="uk-card-header">
            <div className="uk-width-expand">
              <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">
                {person.name}
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="uk-card-body">
            <p>{person.description}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="uk-card-footer">
            <button
              onClick={() => handleLearnMore(person)}
              className="uk-button uk-button-text"
            >
              Learn More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    ) : (
      <div className="uk-placeholder">No users were found!</div>
    )}
  </div>
);

Results.propTypes = {
  handleLearnMore: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  results: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string,
      name: PropTypes.string,
      age: PropTypes.number,
      email: PropTypes.string,
      registered: PropTypes.string,
      description: PropTypes.string
    })
  )
};

export default Results;
```

**components/LearnMore**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const LearnMore = ({ name, email, age, description, registered }) => (
  <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
    <h3 className="uk-card-header">{name}</h3>
    <p>
      <strong>Email</strong>: {email}
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Registered</strong>: {registered}
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Age</strong>: {age}
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Job</strong>: {description}
    </p>
  </div>
);

LearnMore.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  age: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  registered: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default LearnMore;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your onSubmit like this:

```
<form id= "learn-more-form" onSubmit={this.learnMore(obj)}>
    <input type="submit" value="Learn More"/>
</form>
```

Then the function should be:

```
learnMore = (data) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(data) // probably setState with this data so you can display it when it, like this.setState({ currentMoreResults: data })
}
```

Comment: i don't want to console.log, I want to replace the contents of the div with the data. Further, learnMore is executed onSubmit so the results only last about a second and then dissappear

Comment: You need to setState and use that new state value to show your results. Give it a try, your results will stay. See the preventDefault